# I have a secondary OS running on my "D:\" drive, but when I switch to the secondary OS it becomes the "C:\" drive. Is this a real issue?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, multi-boot

I've done dual booting before, and every time before it's always been that the secondary OS would show the hard drive it's installed on as the assigned drive letter on my main OS. However I've installed my secondary OS on this computer (secondary OS is Windows 7) and while I am in it the "D:" drive will be assigned as the "C:" drive until I boot back into my main OS. Is there a reason as to why it wasn't like this with my other setups and is there any real danger here?

Comment: @ChanganAuto So you downvoted my post because I use an unsupported OS? I hope the entire community doesn't do that. By the way, I paid for extended security updates until 2023 so I am going to use it whether you like it or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly as intended.
By convention, PCs boot from the C:\ drive.
This is mapped at boot. It is a variable, not a fixed assignment.

Each OS then carries its own mappings as to what letter any other mounted volume is assigned.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering why when I've done this before the drive I installed it on would continue to have the same letter as it would on my main OS after installation. I've used Kali Linux, Linux Mint and Ubuntu as secondary OSes before and for some reason after installing them the drive would still be assigned what my main OS would assign them. It could just be how I installed it.